# ImportError: No module named manage Django

Tags: python, django, buildout

I am trying to run a Django 1.4 project using buildout (I have the same project in another computer currently working), but somehow it seems that the system is not getting the Django path in the new instalation (although it was installed via pip in a virtualenv).

Here's the output of my pip freeze:

```
(dev-cta)daniel@local:~$ pip freeze
Django==1.4.22
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

After ./bin/buildout without incidents, y try ./bin/django runserver and:

```
(dev-cta)daniel@local:~$ ./project/bin/django runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project/bin/django", line 94, in <module>
    import djangorecipe.manage
ImportError: No module named manage
```

I've tried reinstalling/updating django and the problem is still there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing a package. Install [DjangoRecipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe).

Do a `pip install djangorecipe`.

Comment: I've installed 0.23.1, which was referenced in base.cfg of buildout. Now when I try to runserver I get:

`(dev-cta)daniel@local:~/project/$ ./bin/django runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./bin/django", line 94, in <module>
    sys.exit(djangorecipe.manage.main('website.settings_beta'))

....
*few more lines of file references, can't prompt cause char limit*
....

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file_critical': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/daniel/project/var/log/django-critical-2016-01-18.log' `

Comment: @DanielRamírezTorres - That is a different issue, you should create a new question for that if needed but I think its pretty clear how to fix that. If this answer has solved your question then feel free to mark it as the accepted answer